# Problems in Executing the SP which has while(true) loop in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I know it is not good way and may have many issues. But can anyone tell what are the problems in executing the SP which has while loop.

```
CREATE PROC udpParseData
BEGIN
WHILE(true)
BEGIN
    --logic goes here
END
END

EXEC udpParseData
```

I want to run it like a service. Instead of running a service which check the DB continuously using SQL Dependancy. Any problem with this and also i have a main concern that how to stop the running SP udpParseData. One more option i have is run the same SP in Scheduler JOB. I wanted to know the restrictions and disadvantages of using this.

Comment: Instead of running a service that'l kill your database. Use sql jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do this - even a Windows service doesn't work like that. A Windows service would leverage a `Timer` that wakes up on an interval and starts the message pump.

Write the work you want to execute in a stored procedure and then create a [`Job`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx) on the SQL Server that executes that stored procedure, and setup the times you want it to run. The `Job` takes the place of the `Timer` in the Windows service.

Comment: Thanks Michael that helps a lot. But i am thinking to schedule the job on each boot up. because inside the SP i will use while loop, that itself continuously does the work i want. Only whenever system boots up i want run the JOB again. Is there any issues with that? Or its best to use SP without while loop and run the JOB continuously. I am thinking the performance issue also here. I need to process almost 30000 records per 10min.

Comment: @Pravin, the fact that you're speaking of "on each boot up" concerns me a little. But I've been there, I had to reboot a SQL Server daily one time until I could track down the root issue. But listen, if you have a *job* to do every 10 minutes over 30,000 records then create a stored procedure to handle those 30,000 and run that procedure every 10 minutes using a SQL Job. I have jobs running every single minute - for email notifications - it's not a problem. But ***do not*** build a stored procedure with an infinite `while` loop. Execute the job, continually, on that 10 minute schedule.

Comment: Thanks Micheal. I have one doubt. Consider I am running the JOB every Minute. In that JOB i am executing the SP. Consider Execution of SP in the JOB takes 2minutes then after 1min is there new thread is created and executing SP parallely or it will work serially(means after completing execution its start new execution). You have any idea please clarify this Micheal.